# When is "An Uncivil War in America" set?

Tags: setting, thaddeus-howze

The 2013 short story ["An Uncivil War in America"](https://hubcityblues.com/2013/07/14/an-uncivil-war-in-america/) by Thaddeus Howze describes the aftermath of a race war in the USA. It reads as pretty close to present day, but is there any indication when it is set? Either in the story that I may have missed, or perhaps as a comment by the author.

Comment: Does not seem clear from the story itself.  Here: https://ebonstorm.medium.com/an-uncivil-war-in-america-9fd1e0d141e9  there is a comment on top "In an America not too unlike our own, racial tensions explode into unprecedented and terrifying violence.".  "an America not too unlike our own" sounds somewhat alternate history.  But I don't know if the blurb there is from the author.

Comment: @basya I believe Ebon Storm is Thaddeus Howze's name on medium, but I could be

Comment: @AncientSwordRage -- in that case, perhaps I'll propose this as an answer, if someone doesn't chime in with something more detailed...

Answer (score 5):

It certainly does not seem clear from the story itself.

In one online location of the story, [here](http://ebonstorm.medium.com/an-uncivil-war-in-america-9fd1e0d141e9), there is a blurb at the beginning which appears to be from the author.  On Thaddeus Howze's profile [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus-howze), he has links with the "Ebon Storm" username (thank you to AncientSwordRage and TheLethalCarrot for this information):

> In an America not too unlike our own, racial tensions explode into unprecedented and terrifying violence.

The phrase "an America not too unlike our own" sounds as though this is meant to be alternate history.